# Get values between ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

The more I think of it the more I am confused, could be because it is quite a while that i wrote some complex sql.

I have a table that has a range for a value. Lets call it a range:

```
RANGE
RANGE_ID   RANGE_SEQ   MIN   MAX  FACTOR
       1           1     0    10       1
       1           2    11   100     1.5
       1           3   101           2.5
       2           1     0    18       1
       2           2    19             2
```

And I have anothe table that uses these ranges. Lets call it application

```
APPLICATION
APP_ID   RAW_VALUE  RANGE_ID   FINAL_VALUE
     1         20.0       1          30.0     /*In Range 1, 20 falls between 11 and 100, so 1.5 is applied)*/
     2         25.0       2          50.0
     3         18.5       2          18.5
```

I want to get those `RAW_VALUES` that fall between the ranges. So for range 2, I want those `APP_ID`s that have a `RAW_VALUE` between 18 and 19. Similarly for range 1, I want those `APP_ID`s that have a `RAW_VALUE` between 10 and 11 and 100 and 101.

I want to know whether this is possible with SQL, and some pointers on what I can try. I don't need the sql itself, just some pointers to the approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get you close

```
select app_id,raw_value,aa.range_id,raw_value * xx.factor as FinaL_Value
from Application_table  aa
join range_table xx on (aa.raw_value between xx.min and xx.max)
                  and (aa.range_id=xx.range_id)
```

To get non-matches (i.e. raw_values that do not exist in the table), try this

```
select app_id,raw_value,aa.range_id
from Application_table  aa
left join range_table xx on (aa.raw_value between xx.min and xx.max)
                  and (aa.range_id=xx.range_id)
where xx.range_id is null
```

Comment: `I don't need the sql itself, just some pointers to the approach.`

Comment: Some things are easier to illustrate using SQL then spelling out in English.

Comment: This would include the values IN the ranges as well. For ranges `1 - 10` and `11 - 20`, I want only those values that are between 10 and `11`. So I want `10.5` but not not `5`.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table tq84_range (
  range_id   number not null,
  range_seq  number not null,
  min_       number not null,
  max_       number,
  factor     number not null,
--
  primary key (range_id, range_seq)
);

insert into tq84_range values (1, 1,  0,  10, 1.0);
insert into tq84_range values (1, 2, 10, 100, 1.5);
insert into tq84_range values (1, 3,101,null, 2.5);

insert into tq84_range values (2, 1,  0,  18, 1.0);
insert into tq84_range values (2, 2, 19,null, 2.0);

create table tq84_application (
  app_id     number not null,
  raw_value  number not null,
  range_id   number not null,
  primary key (app_id)
);

insert into tq84_application values (1, 20.0, 1);
insert into tq84_application values (2, 25.0, 2);
insert into tq84_application values (3, 18.5, 2);
```

You want to use a `left join`.

With such a left join, you ensure that *each* record of the left
table (the table appearing prior to `left join` in the
select statement text) will be returned at least once,
even though the where condition doesn't find a record
in the right table.

If `tq84_range.range is null` then you know that the join 
condition didn't find a record in tq84_range, therefore, there
seems to be a gap. So you print `Missing:`.

Since `tq84_application.max_` can be `null` and null appears to
indicate *infinity* or *upper bound* you test the upper limit
with `nvl(tq84_range.max_, tq84_application.raw_value`

Thus, the select statement will become something like:

```
select 
       case when tq84_range.range_id is null then 'Missing: ' 
            else                                  '         '
            end,
       tq84_application.raw_value
  from 
       tq84_application       left join
       tq84_range 
    on
       tq84_application.range_id = tq84_range.range_id 
   and
       tq84_application.raw_value between
       tq84_range.min_ and nvl(tq84_range.max_, tq84_application.raw_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you're saying you only want results from the application table that don't fit in any range? This, for example, would return only the row for app_id = 3 (my own column names and guess at real minimum and maximum amounts):

```
select *
from   APP1 A
where  not exists
         (select null
          from   RANGE1 R
          where  R.RANGE_ID = A.RANGE_ID and A.RAW_VALUE between nvl(R.MINNUM, 0) and nvl(R.MAXNUM, 999999));
```

But, of course, it won't return a factor amount as it matches no rows in the range table so why would the result for app_id = 3 in your example above match up with factor = 1? If your raw_value column is going to be decimal then I would expect the ranges to be decimal too.